# If $X\sim\mathbb{P}_{X}=g_{\ast}(\mathbb{P}_{Y})$ can we find $Y$ such that $X=g(Y)$ at least almost surely?

Tags: probability, random-variables, pushforward

Good morning,

It is the first time I write here on StackExchange, therefore any suggestion to improve my question is really appreciated.

It is known that the distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X}$ of the univariate random variable $$X=g(Y)$$ on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, where $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function (with respect to Borel $\sigma$-algebras) is the push-forward of the distribution $\mathbb{P}_{Y}$ of the univariate random variable $Y$ through $g$, or (following [Wikipedia notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure)) $$\mathbb{P}_{X}=g_{\ast}(\mathbb{P}_{Y}).$$ The equality $X=g(Y)$ holds "omega by omega".

1. Suppose that $g$ is not invertible (for instance, an increasing cadlag function). Is the opposite true? More precisely, if we know that $X$ is an univariate random variable with distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X}=g_{\ast}(\mathbb{P}_{Y})$, can we always construct a random variable $Y$ on the same probability space with distribution $\mathbb{P}_{Y}$ such that $X=g(Y)$ holds at least almost surely?
2. If the answer to the previous point is affirmative, can you suggest a textbook from which I can quote the result?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If we cannot extend the space, then "no":**

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space that has only one outcome. Specfically, assume $\Omega = \{blue\}$. Define $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $X(blue)=0$.

Define the measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $Y$ be Bernoulli-1/2 on some other probability space. Then $X$ has the same distribution as $g(Y)$, but there is no Bernoulli 1/2 variable $Y$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ since that space has only one outcome $blue$.

**If we can extend the space, then "yes":**

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $(\Omega', \mathcal{F}', P')$ be two probability spaces.

-Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on the first space.

-Let $Y':\Omega'\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on the second space.

-Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable function.

Define $X':\Omega'\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $X'=g(Y')$. Suppose $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution.

Suppose that, on the first probability space, there exists a uniformly distributed random variable $U:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ that is independent of $X$. If the original space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ does not have such an independent random variable $U$, we can always extend the space using standard product space concepts.

Theorem 5.10 in Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probabilty* ensures that since $(X', Y')$ lie on the second space, and since $X$ has the same distribution as $X'$, there is a random variable $Y$ on the first space such that $(X,Y)$ has the same joint distribution as $(X',Y')$. (Kallenberg constructs $Y$ as a Borel measurable function of $X$ and $U$).

Define the Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ f(u,v) = g(v)-u \quad \forall (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
Define the
random variables $D:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $D':\Omega'\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align}
D &= f(X, Y)\\
D'&= f(X',Y')
\end{align}
Since $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$ have the same distribution, the random variables $D$ and $D'$ have the same distribution. However, $D'=0$ surely. It follows that $P[D=0]=1$.  That is, $P[g(Y)=X]=1$. So $g(Y)=X$ almost surely.

Comment: Kallenberg's Theorem 5.10 is more general (but also more complicated) because he treats general measurable spaces and Borel spaces. The way I have stated it here holds for $X$ and $Y$ real-valued random variables, meaning they are "random elements" in the standard Borel space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Borel measure.

Comment: The Kallenberg's reference is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! At a very first glance, but I may be wrong, Theorem 5.10 seems connected to the conditional quantile of X given Y. I'll definitely have a more careful read to know more.